# How to start Cisco 2911 with presaved configuration?

Tags: cisco, ios

I briefly configured branch router Cisco 2911 and saved config.

Unfortunately - after rerun Cisco needs "copy startup-config running-config" to read configuration (I really need this - for example to get up interface GigabitEthernet0/0).

How I can save my configuration as the  permanently one and auto started?

Comment: Answer is here - registry http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps233/products_tech_note09186a00800a65a5.shtml

"""In this example, the configuration register shows 0x2142. The router bypasses the startup configuration stored in NVRAM during its boot sequence. This feature is normally used during a password recovery procedure."""

So, the correct answer is to change registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As told by bluszcz in the comment to your question, please take a look to `Configuration register` value in the output of `show version`
It should be set to 0x2102 which you can do with the `config-register 0x2102` command

Answer (score 2):

btw:

copy startup-config running-config

does not replace the current running-config with the startup-config, but merges both into a running-config...

If you need to replace your current-config (e.g. rollback configuration-mistakes), you need to reboot the device or use "configure replace".

tsg

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what it is you're asking, you need to execute a "copy run start" to save your running configuration to the startup configuration.

Comment: No, this one doesn't work. I still have to read manually my config.

Comment: @bluszcz Ok, I'm lost. "copy run start" is the correct way to save a config. Then when you issue a "reload" or the device is power cycled the config you saved is the config used on boot.

Comment: Answer is here - registry http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps233/products_tech_note09186a00800a65a5.shtml

Answer (score 1):

> How I can save my configuration as the permanently one and auto started?

copy running-config startup-config

Comment: I will check in 1-2 hour and post result - I think that I saved it in this way before, but maybe I was wrong